# After Spring boot upgrade to 3.0.6 cannot see trace of requests in Transaction section in Kibana

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, kibana, java-17, elastic-apm

After Spring boot upgrade to 3.0.6 cannot see trace of requests in Transaction section in Kibana.

Before upgrading the Java Spring boot application to 3.0.6 and upgrading the Java to 17, the traces of requests was seen on the Transaction section in Kibana.

Tried even upgrading the Spring boot and also updating the dependencies.

Comment: Can you provide more details on what logging framework and version you are using. Are you seeing the logs in file/console ?

Comment: I am using Slf4j logging framework. The logs related to apm alastic is shown, but no log related to tracing is shown. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/java/current/trouble-shooting.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to see the Trace and Span after adding these 2 elastic configurations :

```
  {
    "name": "ELASTIC_APM_USE_PATH_AS_TRANSACTION_NAME",
    "value": "true"
  },
  {
    "name": "ELASTIC_APM_PROFILING_INFERRED_SPANS_ENABLED",
    "value": "true"
  }
```